# How could I test a BusinessHours class functionality with unit tests

Tags: unit-test, dml, businesshours, dml-operations

I am trying to write a unit test for the following method,

```
public static DateTime addBusinessDays(DateTime startDate, Integer numberOfDays, String businessHoursName){
         Integer numberOfDaysTobeAdded = 8*3600000*numberOfDays;
         BusinessHours bh = getBusinessHourSettings(businessHoursName);
         Datetime endDate = BusinessHours.add(bh.id,startDate,numberOfDaysTobeAdded);
         return endDate;
    }
```

> My questions are:
>
> 1. Why is the salesforce BusinessHours class doesn't support DML
>      operations?
> 2. How could I test a BusinessHours class functionality with unit
>      tests? (without querying the BusinessHours?)

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_businesshours.htm

Says it is supports create(), getUpdated(), query(), retrieve(), update()
So you should be able to insert

Comment: It is annoying that you can not do DML operations on BusinessHours. [This question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33580/set-business-hours-in-apex-test-code) should help.

Comment: I Tried This, 
BusinessHours bh= new BusinessHours(
    MondayStartTime = Time.newInstance(9, 0, 0, 0),
    ............
    IsActive = true,
    IsDefault = true
);
insert bh; BUT it says **DML not allowed on BusinessHours**

Comment: I would rename `numberOfDaysToBeAdded` to `millisecondsToBeAdded`...

Comment: @TimChadwick Have you ever tried it? It is clearly not allowed and there are a fair amount amount of posts about it out there if you do a little googling.

Comment: BusinessHours are available without using SEEALLDATA so you could create a BusinessHours specifically for test methods if you are concerned with them changing.

Comment: I've dealt with this by having the PROD code fetch BusinessHours via an interface method. The PROD code provides a concrete implementation for the interface that fetches `Businesshours` from the database; the testmethod provides a different implementation of the interface that returns a list of `BusinessHours` sobjects that you can assert against.

Answer (score 2):

`BusinessHours` can't be set up in unit tests.

Best bet is to just set one up in the org and be done with it. Probably all your offices *do* have a common holiday like 1st January? Then to make your unit test code office-agnostic, you can do something like this:

```
static Datetime addBusinessDays(Datetime start, Integer time, String office) {

    BusinessHours bh;

    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        //for tests
        bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours LIMIT 1];
    } else {
        //for reals
        bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Name = :office];
    }

    return BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, time, numberOfDays);
}
```

Then your test data revolves around 1st January to meaningfully assert the correctness of any calculations you want to perform.